# Click on any label must execute JQuery function

Tags: jquery

I have a side-menu with labels under it define the menu-items and are dynamically generated. When user-clicks on any item, following code must execute:

```
$("#label").click( function(event) ){
    $.get(
        "../../phplibraries/productlist.php",
    {
        ControlName: 'ulCategoryName',
        Category: 'Beverages'
    },
    function(data) {
        $('#divList').html(data);
    });
});
```

I am not following how to capture click on any label that is actually a menu item.

**-- Edited --**

The HTML of side menu is as below:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    require_once('dbaccess.php');

    $ulName = $_GET['ControlName'];
    $category = $_GET['Category'];

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT pname FROM products WHERE category='".$category."'");
?>
<ul id="<?php echo $ulName; ?>" name="<?php echo $ulName; ?>">
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>
    <label id="lblCategory" name="lblCategory" style="font-size:medium;"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></label><br />
    <!--<li style="font-size:medium;"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></li>-->
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you also post the HTML for your side menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need dynamically loaded labels to get the behavior you described consider using [jQuery live()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live).
in general, you could define your behavior to certain elements, with the needed selector, when creating the menu, and all dynamically created elements who answer to this selector will gain the same behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error in the first line:

```
$("#label").click( function(event) ){
```

should be:

```
$("#label").click( function(event) {
```

And remove the hash (#). `#something` means `select element with ID 'something'`. Since you want to bind this event handler to all your labels simply use `$('label')`.

See jQuery's [manaul on Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) for more information on how to select various elements.

Comment: OP means Original Poster :) just so you know :)

Comment: I had a notion that it is Original Post.

Comment: Well could be :) Both makes sense, but here we refer to the first "post" as question, and everything else as an answer. I'm being nit-picky :)

Answer (score 0):

try removing the hash (#):

```
$("label").click(function(event)){
    $.get("../../phplibraries/productlist.php", {ControlName: 'ulCategoryName', Category: 'Beverages'}, 
    function(data){
        $('#divList').html(data);
    }); 
});
```

This will bind EVERY label. You may want to limit it. E.g.

```
$("#SomeContainerDiv label").click(function(event){
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove '#' from your code rest will fine

Comment: if your label is generated dynamical then you have to use live jquery functionality, 

$('label').bind(function(){});

Answer (score 0):

since you are dynamically generating, I would look into using the .live('click'...) functionality for this one.